# Why is add trigger not working in aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, eventtrigger

Basically. I want all the verisons of files in my bucket called awsbkt870 to another bucket called versions870. So i am using the following lambda function code to do it.

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket = 'awsbkt870'  # Replace with your actual source bucket name
    destination_bucket = 'versions870'  # Replace with your actual destination bucket name

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    # List all objects in the source bucket
    objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket=source_bucket)

    # Iterate through each object and its versions, and copy to the destination bucket
    for obj in objects.get('Contents', []):
        key = obj['Key']

        # List all versions of the current object in the source bucket
        versions = s3.list_object_versions(Bucket=source_bucket, Prefix=key)['Versions']
        
        # Reverse the order of versions
        versions.reverse()

        # Iterate through each version and copy it to the destination bucket
        for index, version in enumerate(versions, start=1):
            version_id = version['VersionId']
            new_key = f"{index}_{key.split('/')[-1]}"

            # Check if the file with the new key already exists in the destination bucket
            try:
                s3.head_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=new_key)
                print(f"Version {index} of {key} already exists in {destination_bucket}/{new_key}")
            except s3.exceptions.ClientError as e:
                if e.response['Error']['Code'] == '404':
                    # File not found, proceed with copying
                    try:
                        s3.copy_object(
                            Bucket=destination_bucket,
                            CopySource={'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': key, 'VersionId': version_id},
                            Key=new_key
                        )
                        print(f"Version {index} of {key} copied to {destination_bucket}/{new_key}")
                    except s3.exceptions.ClientError as e:
                        print(f"Error copying {new_key}: {e}")
                else:
```

Now i want to trigger the function whenever a version gets updated or a file gets added in the source bucket(awsbkt870). But i am getting **"An error occurred when creating the trigger: Unable to validate the following destination configurations"**

[Here is the tigger details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1m0.png)

[here are the policies attached to my function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2KEo.png)

***What do i do to add the trigger?***

I was expecting to add the tigger. I am not able to add the tigger. my test cases with the lambda function are successfull.

Comment: Does the Lambda function's [resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html) allow S3 to invoke the function?

Comment: This doesn't address the question you directly asked, but this function code is *very* wrong based on what you say you want to do. `event` would contain a source bucket, object key, and object version, but this code iterates through all versions of all objects with each upload, which does not make sense. Also, you can't iterate through object versions with a simple ordinal index number and expect to get valid results – you need to correlate version IDs... but none of this seems necessary, since S3 has [native replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot by replication can we copy all versions of the object in source bucket as different objects(i.e each verison behaves as a different object) in destination bucket? How to do it??

Comment: @encoded150 the target bucket would have the same version IDs as the source bucket, accessible independently, but not be different objects. Your code -- and any similar strategy -- fails to provide the expected results if any version is ever removed from the source bucket, because the index numbers slip out of sync.  Given 5 objects, replicated as you expect, then delete 3. Add the 6th, but it's only the 5th in the source, so it's never replicated. because target already has 5.  The 6th in source becomes 6th in target and 5 is forever overlooked.  Strategy unreliable.  What is the purpose?